# How to get rows of a dataframe that contain values between two other values?

Tags: r, dataframe, range

So I want to find values in a column of a data.frame, which are in range of defined values:

```
  example
 [1] 6 2 4 3 5 1
 pos
 [1] 1 3 2
```

I now want to get the values of example for which BOTH of the following statements are TRUE, so that I got only values that lie between `pos - 1` and `pos +1`:

```
if(example < pos - 1)
if(example > pos + 1)
```

And now the real values for my task are within a data.frame. How do I extract the complete rows, which contain these values and build a new pos
`data.frame`.

The expected output for the example would be:

```
result
[1] 2 3 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You said `example` contains only one column, so why are you selecting an unexsisting column using `example[, 4]`? Why wouldn't you provide a reproducible example for starters? I have a feeling that while trying to reproduce your error you will understand when it's coming from in the first place.

Comment: I edited the question, so that is ( I hope) mor helpful for others :)

Comment: The length of `pos` and `example[, 4]` are the same?

Comment: No,  `pos` contains just a few values and I need to check which of the values in `example[,4]` are in the range of those.

Comment: `pos` has only 6 values so its just being recycled. You are not comparing against all the values in `pos` rather each value in `example[, 4]` compared against only one (recycled) value in `pos`. Are you trying to compare *each* values in `example[, 4]` against *each* value in `pos`?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly, what I am trying to do. I want to compare all values of `pos` to all values of `example[,4]` and then get the rows of `example` which contain a value that is in the range of 25 +/- `pos`

Comment: You desired output is unclear. Either way you don't need that huge example. A simple reproducible example would be something like (you can adjust it to closely match your data) `set.seed(1) ; pos <- sample(3) ; example <- sample(6) ; example < pos` and you need to explain what are you expecting to get.

Comment: I am guessing you want this:  `example[(example$V4>30-25 & example$V4<30+25) | (example$V4>70-25 & example$V4<70+25) |... ,] `

Comment: I think you are looking for something like `indx <- sapply(example[, -4], function(x) any(x < pos + 25) | any(x > pos - 25))`. Then just do `example[indx, -4]`

Comment: I now edited the original question so it is a general example. Does your function just leave those rows which meet at least one of my needed conditions? @DavidArenburg

Comment: Yes I tried it, and it works so far, but unfortunately it leaves the other rows just containing N/A instead of leaving only the correct rows. @DavidArenburg

Comment: But my  `pos` contains only 6 values and `example` contains more than thousands of values in my real working set. @DavidArenburg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76866/discussion-between-jadenblaine-and-david-arenburg).

Comment: But I just noticed that it gives out EVERY row, so something in this code is causing this error. @DavidArenburg

Comment: What is your expected output from the provided example?

Comment: added the expected result

Comment: `6` is bigger than `pos + 1` so why didn't it meet the condition?

Comment: Oh, my bad, then I really need to say that I need values that lie BETWEEN pos-1 and pos+1 so they have to meet both condiotions. Edited this in the OP.

Comment: So `example[sapply(example, function(x) any(x > pos - 1) & any(x < pos + 1))]` should work. `4` doesn't meet the second condition so shouldn't be there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set min and max thresholds and then compare each element against them

```
maxind <- max(pos + 1)
minind <- min(pos - 1)
```

Then

```
example[sapply(example, function(x) x > minind & x < maxind)]
## [1] 2 3 1
```

Or, similarly

```
example[example > minind & example < maxind]
## [1] 2 3 1
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
example[between(example, minind, maxind, incbounds = FALSE)]
## [1] 2 3 1
```

Answer (score 3):

So the solution as suggested by @David Arenburg is like this:

```
indx <- sapply(example[, 4], function(x) any(x < pos + 1) & any(x > pos - 1))
```

Then just do

```
example[indx,]
```

This will search a data.frame in the specified column for values that are in the defined range and will just give you the rows of your desire!