# Extract rows of data frame with values between two other values

Tags: r, data.table, range

I have [some data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2h8oq8nzrr5jsnm/sample_data.csv?dl=0) with seven columns. The first six are spatial coordinates of an object's cross section with units in metres, relative to a point X=0 Y=0 in the bottom left corner. The shape's cross section is composed of a mesh of tessellating triangles with each of the point coordinates (X1,Y1. X2,Y2. X3,Y3), representing the corners of the triangles. The seventh column (Z) is a value derived from an analysis assigned to the triangle which has been made by the three point coordinates.

I'm trying to extract the point coordinate and "Z" column data in a narrow band through the middle of the shape. I've taken a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025358/how-to-get-rows-of-a-dataframe-that-contain-values-between-two-other-values) and used David Arenburg's code and the `data.table` package but I can't seem to get it to work; perhaps because I have more than two columns of data?

What I need to do is extract the coordinate and Z data within a 1 cm wide horizontal band through the geometric centre of the shape (half of its height). If any of the point coordinates for any of the triangles falls within the 1 cm band, I would like that entire row of data; ideally in a separate data frame.

Here's what I have so far:

```
data<-sample_data
attach(data)
upper<-(max(data$Y3)/2)+0.005 # the horizontal centreline of the shape plus half a cm
lower<-(max(data$Y3)/2)-0.005 # the horizontal centreline of the shape minus half a cm
library(data.table)
(data[between(data,lower,upper,incbounds=FALSE)])
```

I've also tried these but get the same error message

```
data[data>lower&data<upper]
data[sapply(data,function(x)x>lower&x<upper)]

# Error: Unsupported use of matrix or array for column indexing
```

You can plot the shape with this code if you'd like to see it.

```
plot(X1,Y1,pch=19,cex=0.6)
points(X2,Y2,pch=19,cex=0.6)
points(X3,Y3,pch=19,cex=0.6)
```

Hopefully I've explained this well enough for someone to offer some assistance

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has requested to

> extract the coordinate and Z data within a 1 cm wide horizontal band through the geometric centre of the shape (half of its height). If any of the point coordinates for any of the triangles falls within the 1 cm band, I would like that entire row of data; ideally in a separate data frame.

Unfortunately, the question itself as well as [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46859692/3817004) does only check the `Y` value of point 3 but not the `Y` values of point 1 and point 2. This is not in line with above requirement to select those triangles where *any* of the point coordinates, i.e., either point 1, 2, *or* 3, fall within the 1 cm band.

So, the key issue here is to select relevant *triangles* rather than single *points*.

Below, there are two `data.table` solutions. The first one is using the data in wide format as supplied by the OP, the second one in long format to streamline the code.

#### Wide format

```
library(data.table)
# read data from dropbox
DT <- fread("https://www.dropbox.com/s/2h8oq8nzrr5jsnm/sample_data.csv?dl=1")
# compute horizontal band through the geometric center of the shape
lower <- DT[, mean(range(c(Y1, Y2, Y3)))] - 0.01 / 2
upper <- lower + 0.01
# select row if y value of any point is within the horizontal band 
DT[lower < Y1 & Y1 < upper | lower < Y2 & Y2 < upper | lower < Y3 & Y3 < upper]
```

> ```
>              X1       Y1         X2       Y2         X3       Y3        Z
>   1: 0.00737923 0.218856 0.00710657 0.215950 0.01030030 0.217116  37.1608
>   2: 0.00517517 0.220532 0.00737923 0.218856 0.00761518 0.221670  57.6568
>   3: 0.00679651 0.212962 0.00448935 0.214803 0.00407957 0.211809  16.6649
>   4: 0.00407957 0.211809 0.00644539 0.209902 0.00679651 0.212962  15.2068
>   5: 0.38168000 0.214740 0.38544600 0.212670 0.38533400 0.217001  28.2365
>  ---                                                                     
> 177: 0.08690940 0.224751 0.07950840 0.237030 0.07896900 0.222427  86.2424
> 178: 0.08690940 0.224751 0.07896900 0.222427 0.08592510 0.216536  87.3141
> 179: 0.31252100 0.204228 0.30390000 0.214336 0.30509100 0.195766 127.5630
> 180: 0.01912900 0.209566 0.02296630 0.206891 0.02147170 0.214579  40.5351
> 181: 0.01912900 0.209566 0.02147170 0.214579 0.01702550 0.210148  37.3207
> ```

Note that `mean(range(c(Y1, Y2, Y3)))` is used to compute the y-value of the geometric center instead of `max(data$Y3)/2` because the range of y-values extends below 0:

```
DT[, range(c(Y1, Y2, Y3))]
```

> ```
> [1] -0.00171812  0.43692700
> ```

Furthermore, the condition
`lower < Y1 & Y1 < upper | lower < Y2 & Y2 < upper | lower < Y3 & Y3 < upper`
selects 181 triangles while using only `lower < Y3 & Y3 < upper` selects only 93 triangles.

#### Plotting the data

Using `data.table` syntax, the data can be plotted:

```
# plot all points
DT[, {plot(X1,Y1,pch=19,cex=0.6)
  points(X2,Y2,pch=19,cex=0.6)
  points(X3,Y3,pch=19,cex=0.6)}]
# plot points of selected triangles
DT[lower < Y1 & Y1 < upper | lower < Y2 & Y2 < upper | lower < Y3 & Y3 < upper, 
   {points(X1,Y1,pch=19,cex=0.6, col = "red")
     points(X2,Y2,pch=19,cex=0.6, col = "red")
     points(X3,Y3,pch=19,cex=0.6, col = "red")}]
```

[image]

#### Long format

Each triangle is formed by 3 x- and y-coordinates (plus a z-value). The code can be streamlined if the data is reshaped from wide to long format:

```
# reshape from wide to long with two value columns
mDT <- melt(DT, measure.vars = patterns("X", "Y"), value.name = c("X", "Y"))[
  # append column with triangle id
  , tn := rowid(variable)]
# compute range of horizontal band
Y_range <- mDT[, mean(range(Y)) + 0.005 * c(-1, 1)]
# get triangle ids which fulfill condition and subset original data set
DT[mDT[between(Y, Y_range[1], Y_range[2], FALSE), unique(tn)]]
```

> ```
>              X1       Y1         X2       Y2         X3       Y3        Z
>   1: 0.00737923 0.218856 0.00710657 0.215950 0.01030030 0.217116  37.1608
>   2: 0.00517517 0.220532 0.00737923 0.218856 0.00761518 0.221670  57.6568
>   3: 0.00679651 0.212962 0.00448935 0.214803 0.00407957 0.211809  16.6649
>   4: 0.38168000 0.214740 0.38544600 0.212670 0.38533400 0.217001  28.2365
>   5: 0.00485705 0.217712 0.00710657 0.215950 0.00737923 0.218856  35.5559
>  ---                                                                     
> 177: 0.07138950 0.230589 0.06918600 0.223825 0.07896900 0.222427  69.3878
> 178: 0.31531000 0.223694 0.31960800 0.208014 0.32479400 0.215728 104.4240
> 179: 0.36601500 0.211508 0.37193400 0.210487 0.36756700 0.217592  42.0580
> 180: 0.08690940 0.224751 0.07950840 0.237030 0.07896900 0.222427  86.2424
> 181: 0.01912900 0.209566 0.02296630 0.206891 0.02147170 0.214579  40.5351
> ```

Again, 181 triangles are selected. The long format is also much more handy for plotting:

```
# plot all points
mDT[, plot(X, Y, pch = 19, cex = 0.6)]
# plot points of selected triangles
# using a right join on the triangle ids of the selected triangles
mDT[mDT[between(Y, Y_range[1], Y_range[2], FALSE), .(tn = unique(tn))], on = "tn",
    points(X, Y , pch = 19, cex = 0.6, col = "red")]
```

[image]

#### Explanation of error message

The OP has reported that the following lines return error messages:

```
data[between(data,lower,upper,incbounds=FALSE)]
data[data>lower&data<upper]
data[sapply(data,function(x)x>lower&x<upper)]
```

The reason is that the whole `data` object is used in the subsetting conditions instead of single column vectors.

Comment: Wow! Thank you

I picked up on the `lower < Y1 & Y1 < upper | lower < Y2 & Y2 < upper | lower < Y3 & Y3 < upper` argument and fixed it within my analysis. Great solution. thanks